# How to display two divs with only text inside next to each other?

Tags: html, css

Currently I have two divs:

```
<div id="first">gdsgdsgsd</div><div id="second">aaaaaaa</div>
```

and the output is:

```
gdsgdsgsd
aaaaaaa
```

However I would like to have the output as:

```
gdsgdsgsdaaaaaaa
```

Here's a very plain fiddle for that :) http://jsfiddle.net/6oqrj9oo/1/

Do you have any advices for fixing that?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These `divs` are block level elements so will appear stacked on top of eachother. Try making them `inline` or `inline-block`. Inline elements will sit side by side.

```
#first, #second {
    display: inline;
}
```

Alternatively you could `float` them

Comment: Thanks, that solved my problem, I'll mark it as the correct answer as soon as I can :)

Answer (score 2):

Use `display:inline-block`

```css
div{
    display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id="first">gdsgdsgsd</div><div id="second">aaaaaaa</div>
```